# Some phase plane analysis for $u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)$ with assumptions on $f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the semilinear diffusion equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)
$$
with the following assumptions on $f$ for some $\alpha\in (0,1)$:

- $f\in C^1[0,1]$
- $f(0)=f(1)=0$
- $f'(0) < 0$
- $f(u)<0$ in $(0,\alpha)$
- $f(u)>0$ in $(\alpha,1)$
- $\int_0^1 f(u)\, du>0$

Introduce the moving coordinates $\xi=x-ct$. Plugging this into the equation gives 
$$
-cU_\xi=U_{\xi\xi}+f(U)
$$
which as a system is
$$
\begin{align*}
U_\xi&=V\\
V_\xi&=-cV-f(U)
\end{align*}
$$

For $c=0$, we have the "Energy"
$$
E(U,U_\xi)=\frac{1}{2}(U_\xi)^2+F(U),\qquad F(U):=\int_0^U f(y)\, dy
$$

and, in particular, each trajectory satisfies an equation
$$
E(U,U_\xi)=\textrm{const}.
$$

Now, there is the following part in a paper which I do not understand:

> > Under our hypotheses on $f(u)$ [which I listed above], there is an $\eta\in (0,1)$ such that $F(\eta)>0$. For any $0 < \nu < (2F(\eta))^{1/2}$ the trajectory through $(0,-\nu)$ lies in the strip $U\in [0,1)$ and contains a point of the positive $V$-axis.

1.) Why is there an $\eta\in (0,1)$ with $F(\eta)>0$?

Am I right that $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)>0$; if yes then this implies the existence of such an $\eta$ (Intermediate value theorem?)

2.) Where does the condition $0<\nu<(2 F(\eta))^{1/2}$ come from?

From the energy picture, it is clear to me that by assumption $\int_0^1 f(u)\, du=F(1)-F(0)>0$, we have that there are to hill tops positioned at $U=0, F(0)$ and $U=1, F(1)$ and that the second hill top is higher than the first one. Hence, from the phase plane it is clear to me that there are trajectories through $(u,0)$ and $(0,-v)$ for $u\approx 1$ and some $v>0$. I think the condition $0<\nu <(2 F(\eta))^{1/2}$ has something to do with this energy picture.

Edit.

My idea would be to use
$$
E(U,V)=C \Leftrightarrow V=\pm\sqrt{2C-2F(U)}
$$
which makes sense iff $F(U)\leqslant C$.

If we choose $C=F(\eta)$ then for $0<F(U)<F(\eta)$ we have 
$$
0<\lvert V\rvert<\sqrt{2F(\eta)}
$$

and the trajectories containing $(0,-V)$ are of the described type?

Answer (score 3):

For the first question your argument with the IVT is correct.  For the second note that along any trajectory (writing $' = d/d\xi$)
$$
 \left( \frac{1}{2}|U'(\xi)|^2 + F(U(\xi)) \right)' + c|U'(\xi)|^2 = 0.
$$
This follows by multiplying $-c U' = U'' + F'(U)$ by $U'$ and noticing the total derivative structure.   Now, if $c \ge 0$, then this is a dissipation relation and we can integrate to conclude that 
$$
 \frac{1}{2}|U'(\xi)|^2 + F(U(\xi)) \le \frac{1}{2}|U'(0)|^2 + F(U(0)).
$$
Now, if the trajectory starts with $U(0) =0$ and $U'(0) = -\nu$, then the above inequality tells us that
$$
 \frac{1}{2}|U'(\xi)|^2 + F(U(\xi)) \le \frac{1}{2}\nu^2 .
$$
Assume for the moment that along the trajectory there exists $\xi_0$ such that $U(\xi_0) = \eta $.   Then
$$
F(\eta) = F(U(\xi_0)) \le \frac{1}{2} \nu^2 < F(\eta)
$$
by hypothesis, which is a contradiction.  Thus by the IVT $U(\xi) < \eta$ for all $\xi$.

This is only part of what you want, but I don't think it's actually true that $U(\xi) \ge 0$ for all $\xi$ given what is stated.  In fact, if $U(0) = 0$ and $U'(0) = -\nu$, then by continuity there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $U'(\xi) \le -\nu/2$ for $\xi \in [0,\epsilon)$ and hence 
$$
U(\xi) = U(0) + \int_0^\xi U'(s) ds = \int_0^\xi U'(s) ds \le -\frac{\nu \xi}{2} < 0 \text{ for } \xi \in (0,\epsilon).
$$
This seems to be at odds with the fact that $f$ is only defined on $[0,1]$.  Maybe there's a typo and $U'(0) = \nu$ is supposed to be the initial condition?

Comment: I added my own idea concerning question 2.). Does this make sense?

Comment: You're not free to choose $C$ in your analysis.  The constant $C$ is determined by the initial data and is given by $C = \nu^2/2$ if the trajectory starts at $(0,\pm \nu)$.

Comment: Why do we have $\nu^2/2 < F(\eta)$?

Comment: It's the defining feature of $\nu$, namely that $0 < \nu < (2 F(\eta))^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I have a related question. Suppose $f(u)=\cos(u)-1+\mu$ with $\mu\in (1,2)$. Then in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ there are two zeros of $f$, which I denote by $q_1$ and $q_2$. The equilibrium $q_1$ is stable, while $q_2$ is unstable. Now, I want to establish existence of a front between $q_1$ and $q_1+2\pi$. In particular, $\int_{q_1}^{q_1+2\pi}f(u)>0$. So I am  in the same setting as above, but only on the interval $U\in [q_1,q_1+2\pi]$. But I dont longer have that $F(q_1)=0$ since the potential energy is $F(U)=\int_0^{U}f(y)\, dy$ and not $F(U)=\int_{q_1}^U f(y)\, dy$. - -

Comment: I now would like to use the same kind of argument to argue that any trajectory starting at $(q_0,-\nu)$ intersects the $u$-axis at some $\xi<\eta\in (q_1,q_1+2\pi)$. However, now $F(q_1+2\pi)>F(q_1)>0$. and $q_0\neq 0$ which makes the situation a bit more complicated, doesn't it?.  - Can one make some transformations to bring it back to the same situation as before? Or do I have to argue from the scratch?